# deleted project/group in gitlab is still avaiable in my project/group list

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I created a sample project with some developers, issues, branches and merge requests. then I presented it  and now it's time to delete. but, after deleting from Project's **Settings> Advanced > delete project** , it is still shown in my project list. though the repository is no longer available , it is possible to import a new repository or files into as well as a "delete project" botton just for  me(owner) to delete it. but not works. I closed all issues , merge requests and pipelines in my project, so did members. they closed all issues etc, but still the project/groups appear in first page not only for me, but also for other developers involved. what should I do to remove it from list?

I use `self-managed` gitlab-ee `14.6.1 omnibus` on ubuntu 20.4 and have the owner role on projects and groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can reproduce it consistently (for any project), that would need to be reported as an issue, similar to [239482 "Admin area project delete doesn't work when project list is filtered"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/239482).

But I would test it first on a local self-host GitLab 15.0 instance, in case it is already fixed.

If this is only for this one project, it is possible a reference is still not closed, even though you closed MR, issues and pipelines.
That would still be a bug though.

Comment: as far as I see in the project's menu, there is no open issue nor MR. I also checked pipelines. they were all failed or canceled, nothing pending. Are tehse checks enough?

Comment: @foad322 Yes. If 15.1 (released yesterday) did not address that, that would need to be reported to [GitLab issues](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-com/-/issues?sort=created_date&state=opened).

Comment: I upgraded to gitlab-ee 15.0.5 and it was deleted easily. However, I tried so various ways to reproduce the same issue in 15.0.5 version, but I could not succeed. I think the bug fixed in later version.

Comment: @foad322 I hope it is fixed indeed. The [last release was 16.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/06/22/gitlab-16-1-released/).